# prevent divs from overlapping in grid

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

i try to make a grid layout with css and html with schedules inside.
This is the grid i have now:

[image: not expected behavior]

The div elements are overlapping. How can i can change it that the red square move to next line, like so:
[image]

My code:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let x of [0,1,2,3,4,5]; let i = index">
  <div style="height:70px;min-height: 30px; width: 50px;border: 1px solid black; float:left;">
    <div style="height: 25px;position: relative; background:yellow; width: 150px;min-width:150px;border: 1px solid black;display: block;overflow: auto;" *ngIf="i === 0">
    </div>
    <div style="height: 25px;position: relative; background:red; width: 90px;border: 1px solid black;display: block;overflow: auto;" *ngIf="i === 2">
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this.

I create parent container and add `display: grid` on it. Than create 6 equal colums and 2 equal rows(1 frame each) inside that grid.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(6,1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(2,1fr);
```

Next,in child elements i declare their positions inside grid layout like

```
grid-column: 1 / 4;
grid-row: 1;
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  margin:0;
}

.container{
  height: 10rem;
  width:50vw;
  background-color: bisque;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6,1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2,1fr);
  
}

.first-container{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 1;
  
}

.second-container{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="first-container"></div>
      <div class="second-container"></div>
    </div>
```